# wchar parameters using boost or the Standard Library

Tags: c++, boost

How can I make this code use the boost C++ string library or the Standard Library, to avoid `wchar_t` size definition, and to have a more dynamic string which can be processed much easier? This code uses MFC's `CString`, but I would prefer to use the Standard Library or boost instead.

```
TCHAR       drive[_MAX_DRIVE];
TCHAR       dir[_MAX_DIR];
TCHAR       fname[_MAX_FNAME];
TCHAR       ext[_MAX_EXT];
CString     cstr;

GetModuleFileName(NULL,cstr.GetBuffer(MAX_PATH),MAX_PATH);
cstr.ReleaseBuffer();

_wsplitpath_s(cstr,drive,dir,fname,ext);
cstr=drive;
cstr+=dir;
cstr+=_T("\\myfile.dat");
```

Comment: No STL class provides that, but you can implement it trivially yourself. Return a temporary object from `GetBuffer` which performs assignment into the referenced STL string upon destruction from internal buffer, and provides cast operator to `wchar_t` which points to that buffer

Comment: This isn't really anything to do with the `STL` which only refers to the containers and algorithms parts of the Standard Library (although `std::string` does interoperate with them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the C++ standard [`<filesystem>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) library, specifically its [`path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) class, which has a [`replace_filename()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/replace_filename) method, eg:

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
#include <windows.h>

WCHAR szFileName[MAX_PATH] = {};
GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, szFileName, MAX_PATH);
std:wstring str = std::filesystem::path(szFileName).replace_filename(L"myfile.dat").wstring();
```

Or, since you are using the Win32 API anyway, you could simply use [`PathRemoveFileSpec()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathremovefilespecw) and [`PathAppend()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathappendw) instead (or their safer `Cch` counterparts), eg:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>

WCHAR szFileName[MAX_PATH] = {};
GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, szFileName, MAX_PATH);
PathRemoveFileSpecW(szFileName);
PathAppendW(szFileName, L"myfile.dat");
std:wstring str = szFileName;
```

If you really want to avoid the `MAX_PATH` restriction, you will have to call `GetModuleFileName()` in a loop, increasing the size of the buffer on each iteration, until it finally succeeds:

```cpp
std::wstring wFileName(MAX_PATH, L'\0');
do {
    DWORD dwSize = GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, wFileName.data(), wFileName.size()); // or &wFileName[0] before C++17
    if (dwSize < wFileName.size()) {
        wFileName.resize(dwSize);
        break;
    }
    wFileName.resize(wFileName.size() * 2);
}
while (true);
// use wFileName as needed...
```

Comment: You ignored const-correctness in the second half. "Works in current compiler versions", but is undefined behavior and in direct violation of the API specification of `std::wstring::c_str()`, which states explicitly that you must not ever modify the internal string.

Comment: @Ext3h I didn't ignore it, it was simply a typo, I meant `data()` instead. I have fixed it

Comment: the first two methods look interesting, but the last one with the loop I don't see any good for calling the system function in a loop

Comment: I can't get the std::filesystem to compile, unless I use std::experimental::filesystem::path, I have VS2019 and the latest boost library

Comment: @MarioM You need to select C++17 as the language standard in the compiler settings.

Comment: @Ext3h thanks! I had it only for the Release configuration, and not for debug :)

Comment: @Ext3h a non-const version of `data()` was introduced in C++17, specifically to allow modifying the string's internal array data. Which C++11 guarantees is contiguous, making it suitable as an output buffer (which was already safe to do prior to C++11 in *most* implementations, just without a standard guarantee)

Comment: @MarioM modern Windows allows apps to opt-in to use paths longer than `MAX_PATH`. `GetModuleFileName()` will fail if the path is longer than the supplied buffer. Hence the loop.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I understand, but if you do a file scan in folders with that function it will freeze

Comment: @MarioM works fine for me. You are probably just using it the wrong way.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I mean it will freeze because it will take a long time if there are over 100k files

Comment: @MarioM that is not the fault of the filename parsing code, it just takes a long time to enumerate that many files using standard APIs. If speed is an issue, you usually have to go to a lower level and access the filesystem metadata directly. Otherwise, to avoid freezing the app, move the enumeration to a separate thread, or at least update your UI between iterations.

Comment: @RemyLebeau My bad I thought it increases the buffer 1 by 1 byte, but it doubles every time the MAX_PATH

Answer (score 1):

This little helper works whenever you have to deal with APIs which contains C-style return-by-reference parameters, but you want to use exclusively types following RAI.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

/**
 * Wrap an instance of class S for C-style return-by-reference
 * with base-type T and maximum length N.
 *
 * Use is required when S only supports modification by methods,
 * and direct modification of internal buffer is forbidden.
 */
template<class S, class T, size_t N = 1>
class ref_param
{
public:
    ref_param() = delete;
    ref_param(const ref_param&) = delete;
    ref_param(ref_param&&) = delete;
    
    ref_param(S& ref) : _ref(ref), _storage{} {}
    ~ref_param()
    {
        _ref = _storage;
    }
    
    operator T*()
    {
        return _storage;
    }
    
private:
    S& _ref;
    T _storage[N];
};

// Specialization for single value
template<class S, class T>
class ref_param<S, T, 1>
{
    public:
    ref_param() = delete;
    ref_param(const ref_param&) = delete;
    ref_param(ref_param&&) = delete;
    
    ref_param(S& ref) : _ref(ref), _storage{} {}
    ~ref_param()
    {
        _ref = _storage;
    }
    
    operator T*()
    {
        return &_storage;
    }
    
private:
    S& _ref;
    T _storage;
};


extern "C"
{
    // example function with C style return-by-reference
    void foo(char* ret, size_t size)
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i)
        {
            ret[i] = i + 'a';
        }
        ret[size - 1] = 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string bar;
    foo(ref_param<std::string, char, 32>(bar), 32);
    std::cout << bar;
    return 0;
}
```

This pattern works with other types such as `ComPtr`s too, essentially everything which has an assignment operator on the C++ side just works.

Comment: Thanks! Can you add another snipped on how to use this?

Comment: Take a look further down, example usage is included.

Comment: I see that you are using char, does this also work with wchar ?

Comment: If you use `wchar_t` and `std::wstring`, yes, it does. Or just `ref_param<decltype(bar), decltype(bar)::value_type, 32>(bar)`, if you would like it generic for all string types.

Comment: I don't know why such a function is not included in boost or standard library

Comment: Because it ain't that generic. It works fine for strings (as dynamic lengths are also marked by the null-terminal), and it works fine for single return values (all types), but if you have e.g. something like `example(int *buf, size_t *size_in_and_out)`, you can't copy from fixed size buf to a `std::vector` unless you have also captured that size field, too.